# Web App security: Ask an idle user if he wants to continue

Tags: security

I have had a requirement for our web app (under relevant section and sub-section)which says:

Session management

- Session-timeout:

> The users should remain logged in for a fair amount of time; The
>   session should not get timed out in any case and before logging out we
>   must have a pop-up screen asking if you want to log out or continue.
>   
>   Also, just to re-iterate this is not a requirement about logout feature.
>   I believe this is a strange one and a nightmare as it thinks an idle user would respond to the alert, which makes no sense to me and hence the implementation.

But I am quite interested to hear people's thoughts on this requirement. If you think its valid, reason and how to go about doing this? and if you think this is not a valid requirement, please share your reasons as well.

Thanks,
Sumanth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that if Such a popup os shown to prevent timeout sessions while the user is for example reading a long or complex text or just received a phone call, the popup should itself have a timeout. Once the timeout expires the popup is shown with its own timeout, let's say 10 secs, and if the user doesn't answer the session should be terminated.
I have seen the approach you have been requested in other web pages but without the second timeout security would be at risk.

Comment: Thanks Picarus. A second timeout does make absolute sense.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist that it is not a log-out feature then I can think of a reason:

Inactivity begins when a user's attention shifts to something other than your site. It could be caused by anything from attending a phone call, reading emails, accidentally/purposefully closing browser/computer or moves physically away.

In the last 2 cases, there is nothing you can to to get the attention back, but in the other cases, an `alert()` box is a good visual cue to get the attention back. It is at this point that the user can make a conscious decision of either prolonging the session, or ignoring/terminating it.

`alert()`'s tend to be better than just modal `div`'s because, in cases where the browser window is blurred/unfocused/minimised, it makes the OS provide a visual cue, by say, flashing the taskbar.

A example of where I have seen this behaviour enforced is banking sites. Again, this behaviour of forcing the user's attention is acceptable on a sensitive website like banking, but I personally would hate seeing other ones, like Google or Facebook, doing it.

So think of your user and use it wisely.

Comment: Thanks Pratik. The end-user is an investment bank and may be that explains the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're interpreting the spec wrong.

Sounds to me like sessions should never expire on their own, and *when the user initiates a log-out*, there should be some sort of confirmation.

Comment: Thanks Tyler. I have edited my description to quote that this is not  a logout feature requirement, but a idle-session timeout feature.

Comment: I still think you're reading it wrong, and it IS about a log out feature.

Comment: I wish I was wrong. But, I can confirm that I have spoken to the product owner about this and this is not a logout feature.

Comment: I have to agree with Tyler on this one. The spec clearly states that there should be no timeout. Obviously, if this is not the case, the spec should be changed to match what is intended.